# Why am i getting The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) java.math.BigDecimal, java.math error message

Tags: java, bigdecimal

```
Collections.sort(employees, new Comparator<Employee>() {

    public int compare(Employee s, Employee s1) {
        int comp = s.getName().compareTo(s1.getName());
        if (comp != 0) {    // names are different
            return comp;
        }
        return s.getSalary() - s1.getSalary();
    }
});
System.out.println(employees);

}
```

Comment: hat are you trying to do ? Please develop your problem.

Comment: As of Java 8, you can write this as `employees.sort(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName).thenComparing(Employee::getSalary));`.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`BigDecimal.compareTo(BigDecimal)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo(java.math.BigDecimal)) which already does all the logic for you:

```
return s.getSalary().compareTo(s1.getSalary());
```

The `-` (minus) operator is only defined for the primitive numbers and their dedicated wrapper type.

Answer (score 2):

An easier approach to define the `Comparator`, in Java 8+:

```
Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName).thenComparing(Employee::getSalary)
```

Answer (score 2):

As the other mentionned, this is not the best way to handle the problem you showed, however, one can not use minus operator on BigDecimal. You need to use the substract method to avoid that error.

```
//s.getSalary() - s1.getSalary();
BigDecimal diff = s.subtract(s1);
```

You can then cast that diff to int using `.intValue()`. Be careful thoug, as it may produce side effects because of the information loss from BidDecimal to int...

Comment: `BigDecimal.subtract()` will not return an int, so that won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The Java Language Specification ([JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html)) describes the applicability of the `-` operator for arithmetic operations:

> [15.18. Additive Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18)
>
> **In every case, the type of each of the operands of the binary - operator must be a type that is convertible ([§5.1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)) to a primitive numeric type, or a compile-time error occurs.**

The type `BigDecimal` is neither a primitive numeric type (such as `int`, `short`, `float`, `double`) nor is it convertible to a one. In contrast, although `Integer`, `Float`, `Double`and `Short` are also not primitive numeric types, the `-` operator is defined for them as they can be converted to their primitive counterparts ([JLS-5.1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)).

As already pointed out in other answers, use [BigDecimal.compareTo(BigDecimal)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo-java.math.BigDecimal-) to compare `BigDecimal` instances.